# What's the maximum length of an utterance in LUIS

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to train an LUIS app to differentiate between examples of textual input that are a bit longer, about a paragraph in length. In the documentation I've seen, most of the examples are shorter utterances, a sentence or shorter. Can I use LUIS with longer examples for each intent? Is there a limit on the length of utterance I can use for LUIS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use LUIS with example utterances longer than a sentence. The maximum length of an utterance in LUIS is 500 characters. You can train your LUIS app with up to 10000 utterances.

Comment: There limit for utterances is a lot higher, at least in eu LUIS. I trained services with over 10k utterances. Anyway, it's a bad idea to have them so many